# Limits of covariance and correlation

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim N(0, 1)$ and let $Y=cX$. Compute:

a) $\lim_{c\to 0^{+}} \operatorname{Corr}(X,Y)$
b) $\lim_{c\to 0^{-}} \operatorname{Corr}(X,Y)$

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)
&= E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) \\
&= cE(X^2) - cE(X)^2 \\
&= c\operatorname{Var}(X) \\
&= c
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Corr}(X, Y)
&= \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)}} \\
&=\frac{c}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(cX)}}\\
&= \frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2\operatorname{Var}(X)}}\\
&= \frac{c}{|c|}
\end{align*}

So, we have $\operatorname{Corr}(X, Y) < 0$ as $c \to 0^-$ $\operatorname{Corr}(X, Y) > 0$ as $c \to 0^+$
Is this correct?
As well, why is this result important and or useful?

Comment: What do you think is the value of $\displaystyle \frac{c}{|c|}$ for $c > 0$? for $c < 0$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, it should be 1 for c > 0 and -1 for c < 0. But is the result a prep for later work?